# Find winner in a tic tac toe match

Tags: c, arrays, char

I know people asked this before but I didn't understand the answers.

Assume you have a `char board[3][3]` as a parameter in the function and that
you need to return 1 if the X's won, -1 if the O's won or 0 if no one won yet OR if it's a tie.

```
int checkforwin(char board[3][3]);
```

that's the declaration for the function.

Any idea for non primitive testing for winning by one of the opponents?

Comment: just check all possibilities?

Comment: write out all the ways someone can win the game, then write some code to check for those possibilities.

Comment: Look at the Code Project web site's C-Sharp winner code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432297/Tic-Tac-Toe-Game-Programming-Using-Csharp.

Comment: @RedAlert indeed but at non primitive way, a simple algorithm - not just a bunch of if statements.

Comment: It's amazing that all the Related questions have the keyword 'Tic Tac Toe'.

Comment: @TJ even more amazing that none of them suggests a good answer but a bunch of unorganized IF statements

Comment: Isn't the only way to win not to play?

Comment: Checking all the possibilities is a perfectly good way to do this, even it is "primitive". There is no need to make it more complicated than it needs to be. All you would achieve is making the code harder to understand and more prone to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one keeps a count on each row/column/diagonal.

If the count reaches 3, it indicates three `X`s in a line.
Similarly, -3 indicates three `O`s in a line.
Any other value indicates no winner.

There are 4 blocks in the code:

- Check the Rows
- Check the Columns
- Check One Diagonal
- Check the other Diagonal.

This has a lot of repeated code, and violates the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle of good code.
But it is pretty easy to understand.

```
int CheckTicTacToe(char board[3][3])
{
    int count = 0;
    int row, col;

    // Check each of 3 rows:
    for(row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(col=0; col < 3; ++col)
        {
            count += (board[row][col] == 'X')?  1 :
                     (board[row][col] == 'O')? -1 : 0;
        }
        if (count == 3 || count == -3)
        {
            return count / abs(count); // Return either 1 or -1
        }
    }

    // Check each of 3 columns.
    for(col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(row=0; row < 3; ++row)
        {
            count += (board[row][col] == 'X')?  1 :
                     (board[row][col] == 'O')? -1 : 0;
        }
        if (count == 3 || count == -3)
        {
            return count / abs(count); // Return either 1 or -1
        }
    }

    // Check Left-to-Right downward Diagonal:
    count = 0;
    for(col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
    {
        count += (board[col][col] == 'X')?  1 :
                 (board[col][col] == 'O')? -1 : 0;
    }
    if (count == 3 || count == -3)
    {
        return count / abs(count); // Return either 1 or -1
    }

    // Check Left-to-Right upward Diagonal
    count = 0;
    for(col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
    {
        count += (board[col][2-col] == 'X')?  1 :
                 (board[col][2-col] == 'O')? -1 : 0;
    }
    if (count == 3 || count == -3)
    {
        return count / abs(count); // Return either 1 or -1
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three approaches to solving the problem of detecting a winner in a tic-tac-toe game.  There's the brute force method, the algorithmic method, and the data-driven method.

The brute force method consists of a series of `if` statements.  Since there are only 8 ways to win a tic-tac-toe game, only 8 `if` statements are needed to determine the winner.  Consequently, the brute force method compares well to other methods since it has a relatively small number of lines of code, simple, easy to read code, a relatively small executable size, and fast execution speed.  The brute force method is the best method because the game of tic-tac-toe is trivial.  A slightly more complicated game, like Connect Four, may require more advanced coding techniques, but tic-tac-toe is best solved with simple `if` statements.

The algorithmic method has been demonstrated in the other responses to this question.  David Syzdek's algorithm is by far the best of the algorithms, but is somewhat of a hybrid solution, since it reduces eight `if` statements to four `if` statements through the use of a `for` loop.  Note that his algorithm still has hard-coded indices scattered throughout the code.

The data-driven method uses an initialized data set to abstract the problem, so that the code is fully generic, and all of the messiness is gathered into the data set.  Here's what the code looks like using a data-driven solution.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    int valid;
    int rowA, colA;
    int rowB, colB;
    int rowC, colC;
}
    stPath;

static stPath paths[] =
{
    { true,   0, 0,   0, 1,   0, 2 },   // top row
    { true,   1, 0,   1, 1,   1, 2 },   // middle row
    { true,   2, 0,   2, 1,   2, 2 },   // bottom row
    
    { true,   0, 0,   1, 0,   2, 0 },   // left column
    { true,   0, 1,   1, 1,   2, 1 },   // middle column
    { true,   0, 2,   1, 2,   2, 2 },   // right column
    
    { true,   0, 0,   1, 1,   2, 2 },   // TL to BR diagonal
    { true,   0, 2,   1, 1,   2, 0 },   // TR to BL diagonal
    
    { false,  0, 0,   0, 0,   0, 0 }    // end of list
};

int checkforwin(char board[3][3])
{
    // assumes that board array uses 'X' 'O' and <sp> to mark each position
    
    for (stPath *pptr = paths; pptr->valid; pptr++)
    {
        int a = board[pptr->rowA][pptr->colA];
        int b = board[pptr->rowB][pptr->colB];
        int c = board[pptr->rowC][pptr->colC];
        
        if (a == b && b == c && a != ' ')
            return (a == 'X') ? 1 : -1;
    }
    
    return 0;    // no winner yet
}
```

Note that I'm not advocating a data-driven solution to this particular problem, since the problem itself is too trivial to warrant a data-driven solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do something like the following. You could use if statements without the for loops, however this reduces the size of the source code.

```
// board[3][3]:
//    [0][0] | [1][0] | [2][0]
//    -------+--------+-------
//    [0][1] | [1][1] | [2][1]
//    -------+--------+-------
//    [0][2] | [1][2] | [2][2]
//
int checkforwin(char board[3][3])
{
    int x;

    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
      // check vertical lines
      if ((board[x][0] != '\0') && 
          (board[x][0] == board[x][1]) && 
          (board[x][0] == board[x][2]))
         return(board[x][0] == 'O' ? -1 : 1);

      // check horizontal lines
      if ((board[0][x] != '\0') &&
          (board[0][x] == board[1][x]) && 
          (board[0][x] == board[2][x]))
         return(board[0][x] == 'O' ? -1 : 1);
    };

    // check top left to bottom right diagonal line
    if ((board[0][0] != '\0') && 
       (board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && 
       (board[0][0] == board[2][2]))
      return(board[0][0] == 'O' ? -1 : 1);

    // check bottom left to top right diagonal line
    if ((board[2][0] != '\0') && 
       (board[2][0] == board[1][1]) &&
       (board[0][0] == board[0][2]))
      return(board[2][0] == 'O' ? -1 : 1);

    // no winner
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If-statements are the way to go with this kind of data structure. You can use bitmasks, but in the case of the given datastructure with string elements (`'X' 'O'`), the bitmasks will be really ugly and just make things unnecessarily complex. The shortest and clearest way to do the test is with If-statements.

If you used a different data structure you might be able to make things simpler. For example, if the board is stored as a bit array '`011011001`', then bitmasks are a lot cleaner.

Comment: But each position on the board can have three states, 'x' 'o' or blank, so you need 18 bits to represent all the possible states of the board.

Comment: @user3386109 You use a second bitmap to indicate whether a square is occupied or not.

Comment: Sounds good, but then I'm curious to know what the resulting code looks like, and whether it's actually simpler and/or cleaner than the eight `if` statement solution.